# How to split a Grid row into two columns?

Tags: wpf, grid-layout

I have the Grid layout with 3 rows.How do i split the 3rd row into 2 columns.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="0.75*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="0.25*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="36"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Two ways you can do it:

- Use nested layouts. Put another `Grid` in the third row, and have two columns in that sub-grid.

  ```
  <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions> ... </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <ThingInFirstRow Grid.Row="0" />
      <ThingInSecondRow Grid.Row="1" />
      <Grid Grid.Row="2">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition />
              <ColumnDefinition />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ThingInLowerLeft Grid.Column="0" />
          <ThingInLowerRight Grid.Column="0" />
      </Grid>
  </Grid>
  ```
- Stick with one `Grid`, give it two columns, and make the things in the first two rows span across both columns using `ColumnSpan`.

  ```
  <Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions> ... </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ThingInFirstRow Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
      <ThingInSecondRow Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
      <ThingInLowerLeft Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
      <ThingInLowerRight Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
  </Grid>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="0.75"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.25"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="36"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>       
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```